# How to update SqlLite database when application new version upgrade for xamarin ios

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am implementing one xamarin form application and in that, I am using sqllite database. It is working fine if application installed for the first time but if I update application and there is a change in database E.g "Add a new table or add a new column" than everytime it is crash application.

**Xamarin.Android**

Using SQLiteOpenHelper class we can create or modify an existing database.

**Xamarin.iOS**

I have not found any suitable solution for the same. Is there any way to modify an existing database for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Are you using sqlite-net-pcl nuget package for SQLite in Android and iOS both?

Comment: I recommend you use EntityFramework Core (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore) to share all database logic between projects. In EF Core you only have execute a Migration function on start to apply all model changes.

Comment: yes I have installed sqlite-net-pcl nuget package for SQLite in Android and iOS both